# vars is not evaluated in the body of http requester in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

How to pass the value of variable (Vars) in body section of http requester in Mule 4?

For example : I want to construct a string like below in the body  of http requester

{"Script":"Select ID from Student where StudenName = 'tom'"}

The student name in where condition should be a variable. I tried below but the value of vars.name is not getting replaced during runtime .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it inside quotes. This should work

```
#[{"Script":"Select ID from Student where StudentName = '" ++ vars.name ++ "'"}]
```

Comment: It is giving this #[{"Script":"Select ID from Student where StudentName = tom"}]..but my expected result is #[{"Script":"Select ID from Student where StudentName = 'tom' "}] (value of vars.name inside single quotes)

Comment: Sorry, missed the single quotes. You'll just need to add the single quotes inside the string. I have updated the example